# Свойство hint у Edittext криво работает

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

При использовании API-22 в EdiText-е вместо слов "Введите пароль" отображается набор букв: Ддзжкфз"свтрню. При изменении версий Api, hint отображается верно.

Comment: Ну... может в библиотеках баг... Попробуйте support-lib версию поменять/обновить

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
Присутствует ли это в `.xml` файле?

Comment: Да присутствует.

Comment: Странно... просто у меня тоже почти везде присутствует hint в EditText'ах и работает везде одинаково с API 15 до API 23. Скиньте код EditText'a посмотрим что по чем.

Comment: 1. У вас точно во всех файлах объявлена кодировка UTF-8 (а не windows-1251) и вы ее не меняли? 2. Как добавляете `hint`: через ресурсы или хардкор стринг? Если второй вариант, то используйте вместо этого ресурсы.

Comment: '<EditText
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/editTextPass"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:background="@drawable/border_of_edit_text"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:hint="@string/password"
        />' @whalemare